# windows phone application runs in lock screen theme

Tags: c#, windows-phone, locking, screen

I am creating a windows mobile app which will function in lock screen as a theme. It's being enabled as lock screen notification but not as a theme.

Please let me know how to make this happen?

I am using Phonegap technology,
Normal HTML, CSS and with Javascript.

Comment: What you try ? put your stuff

Comment: Hi, I am using phone gap technology, only html and css file is there...